# How do I add a search bar to my activity that can search a list of Buttons in a Linear Layout?

Tags: android, search, searchview

I want to add a search bar so that the user can search a list of buttons to find what they want quicker. 
I have about 15 buttons in a Linear Layout inside a Scroll View (Vertical).
I want the results to show as a few buttons in a vertical line. After searching the web, I could not answer my question. Thank you in advance.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.boys.fishkeeper.Categories">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/categoryScrollView"
        style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.ScrollView"
        android:layout_width="330dp"
        android:layout_height="457dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/barbsButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Barbs"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                tools:background="@color/searchColor" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/tetrasButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Tetras"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                tools:background="@color/searchColor" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/livebearersButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Livebearers"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                tools:background="@color/searchColor" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/gouramisButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Gouramis"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                tools:background="@color/searchColor" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/cichlidsButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Cichlids"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                tools:background="@color/searchColor" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bettaButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Betta"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                tools:background="@color/searchColor" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/rasborasButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Rasboras"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                tools:background="@color/searchColor" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/daniosButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Danios"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                tools:background="@color/searchColor" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/snakeheadsButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Snakeheads"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                tools:background="@color/searchColor" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/mormyridsButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Mormyrids"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                tools:background="@color/searchColor" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/catfishButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Catfish"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                tools:background="@color/searchColor" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/knifefishButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="KnifeFish"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                tools:background="@color/searchColor" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/loachesButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Loaches"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                tools:background="@color/searchColor" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/pufferfishButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Pufferfish"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                tools:background="@color/searchColor" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/plecsButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Plecs"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                tools:background="@color/searchColor" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firsly set id to your LinearLayout, then use findViewById() in your activity, then create method to identify which button will be visible

```
public void filter(String seaarchText) {
   for (int i = 0;i < linLay.getChildCount();i++) {
       Button button = linLay.getChildAt(i);
       if (button.getText().toString().contains(searchText)) {
           button.setVisibility(View.Visible);
       } else 
           button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   }
}
```